# How to prevent eval to parse variable?

Tags: php, variables, eval

I'm using a CMS that uses eval to parse templates. Now I need to write $mycar in the page without parsing it. How can I do it?

Comment: You can't. This is why you don't use `eval()`.

Comment: Escape the `$`: `\$mycar`

Comment: I already tried, it shows only \ on the page

Comment: `eval` is evil.

Comment: Won't single quoting `'$mycar'` work?